# Adding files in Xcode 4: ensure the path is relative to the project/how to change path?

Tags: xcode4, relative-path

In Xcode 4, I can't add files/resources to my project without having the Relative-to-Group path end up something like: `../../workspace/Project/Resources/thing.png`

Ideally I would have `Resources/thing.png`.

I have tried every possible combination of adding folders, files, making new groups. I wish to keep my resources in a folder within my project directory. If I omit the folder, clearly my assets will be relative to the project — just "thing.png" under the project's root.

Is there any way to change the path of a *single file* (I already know how to 'change the location the group represents') such that I can set the location manually (such as in Xcode 3, where this path crap would happen as well).

Answer (score 9):

My dirty, but simple solution to this:

1. Reveal the project in finder
2. Rightclick the *.xcodeproj file and choose "Show Package Contents"
3. Open the project.pbxproj file with a text editor (e.g. TextWrangler)
4. Find & Replace the absolute "../../../whatever/this/path/is/in/your/case/" part of all file and/or group paths with ""
5. Save the file and open the project in Xcode (it even worked when the project was already opened in Xcode)

Comment: Thank you for the trick. Apple should've enabled manual path editing in Xcode (even if it were an alternative menu—one where Option needs to be pushed). I wonder if they did exactly that but left it disabled (Terminal defaults hack, anybody?).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. It turned out that the problem was Dropbox that would rewrite the paths for Xcode for some reason.

**Moving the project to another location outside of my Dropbox solved the issue.**

Comment: I was not doing this under Dropbox, just under the filesystem. It seems to be an issue with Xcode for me.

Comment: Dropbox doesn't edit files, and thus doesn't rewrite paths. Using the Xcode project on multiple computers using Dropbox, causes *Xcode* to rewrite the paths because of the different paths. The solution is easy: make sure all "dependencies" are in the Dropbox folder and that all paths are relative. The Dropbox's hierarchy doesn't change, so relative paths are fantastic for this purpose. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Under the same area in which you change the groups represented folder, (directly under the Location popup in the Identity and Type group of the File Utility area), there's a small icon to the right of the file name. Click that and choose the file again. That will update the path.